# Is there any way to increase gap between graph and range selector in dygraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, dygraphs

[image]

Is there any method exists to increase the gap between graph and range selector in dygraph? x- axis label is strike out by the range selector.

Comment: do you have any live demo we can check?

Comment: Sorry this is a company project. I cant do that. could you please reffer dygraph's official site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without CSS hacking by setting the [`xAxisHeight` option](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#xAxisHeight):

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  showRangeSelector: true,
  xAxisHeight: 50
});
```

See [full example](https://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/10256/).

Answer (score 2):

you need to increase `top` value like below

```
canvas.dygraph-rangesel-bgcanvas, canvas.dygraph-rangesel-fgcanvas {
    top: 250px!important;
}
img.dygraph-rangesel-zoomhandle {
    top: 257px!important;
}
```

change the `top` value based on your need

see live demo http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/10252/

hope it helps

**Update**

you can limit your code by assigning parent class for ex:

```
.mygraph canvas.dygraph-rangesel-bgcanvas, .mygraph canvas.dygraph-rangesel-fgcanvas {
    top: 250px!important;
}
.mygraph  img.dygraph-rangesel-zoomhandle {
    top: 257px!important;
}
```

so your css doesnt affect others css

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to push the above code in dygraph settings? I mean i the angular code?Because I need above arrangements in particular section only.Currently it will load every graphs

Comment: I tried it in the same page but , if one graph is ok then other one goes wrong